# Telosys - How to generate files outside the current project location?

Tags: code-generation, telosys

I'm using Telosys code generator (the CLI tool).

Is it possible to generate files outside Telosys Tools project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can define the destination folder used by the generator.

Just edit the “**telosys-tools.cfg**” file (in the "TelosysTools" folder )

and set the “**SpecificDestinationFolder**” property

Example for **Linux** :

```
SpecificDestinationFolder=/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Example for **Windows** :

```
SpecificDestinationFolder=C\:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3
```